# С++ диаграмма классов Visual Studio 2022. Не могу добавить класс к отображению

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, uml

И опять богоспасаемая и всеми любимая (нет) программа Vusial Studio заставляет меня обращается с просьбой о помощи! У меня возникла на ровном месте, проблема с диаграммой классов на С++. Хочу добавить класс к отображению и.... (путем перетаскивания из Обозревателя решения в диаграмму)

[image: ы]

Как с этим бороться не имею ни малейшего понятия. Может быть это как то связано с добавлением проекта в систему контроля версий.

Вот так выглядит схема проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй обновить документы или отвязать проект от GITa